# What is the best method for imputing binary (or integral/count) data?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, data-imputation, multiple-imputation

I have a longitudinal dataset, and I want to create a composite score by including five healthy lifestyles to measure the overall lifestyle over time (use as predictor). Each lifestyle is a binary variable (e.g., 1 = Yes, 0 = No). A problem here is that each individual lifestyle more or less has some missing data during the longitudinal follow-up, and once they are added together additively, there will be even more missing data collectively, which reduces the sample size (total longitudinal observations).

Currently, I have tried to impute the missing data for each individual lifestyle based on the data from the adjacent time point (e.g., the answer available at the next/previous time point). However, some of my collaborators say this is not a good method. They recommend multiple imputation, but the individual lifestyle factor in my analysis is binary (or integral), and the value imputed by multiple imputation is not always integral.

What is the best approach to address this problem under this scenario? Is my approach better, or should I do multiple imputation?

Comment: *They recommend multiple imputation, but the individual lifestyle factor in my analysis is binary (or integral), and the value imputed by multiple imputation is not always integral.*---Could you clarify what you mean here? Do you mean that the MI adds other types of values in the imputation?

Comment: what MI library are you using. There is no reason why MI can't give you binary outputs. see eg https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mice/versions/3.16.0/topics/mice details section methods, eg predictive mean matching https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/sec-pmm.html

Comment: @seanv507 That's super helpful! Thanks!

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrandI don’t know much about multiple testing. Initially, I thought that treating an individual's lifestyle—which is actually binary, with responses of 0 and 1—as continuous could lead to multiple imputation yielding non-integer values like 0.8. This approach isn't very reasonable because it's impossible to have a a healthy lifestyle, such as 0.8. Although some have suggested rounding to the nearest integer, this method lacks precision. However, I've now discovered that there are some R packages designed to handle binary predictors, and I plan to experiment with these. Thanks!